# How can I correct smudged font rendering in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, fonts

I recently started working in VS2010 and noticed right away that the font I use, Consolas, doesn't pop like it does in VS2008. First I thought my settings didn't get imported, but I checked and Consolas was the default text!

It's a really minor detail, the sort of stuff that Mac users are known for, but on the left is the slightly blurry VS2010 font rendering and on the right is the VS2008 rendering. It really stands out on the legs of the 'm' and any letter with tight spacing.

Anyone know how to correct? Something I can do in Windows7 font rendering?

```
   VS2010                 VS2008
![comparison of text rendering between VS2010 and VS2008][2]
```

Okay I found the solution. I had to run the ClearType wizard again. The font is stronger, bolder, colors are still the same. Blues and greens are much lighter under GDI.
[image: comparison screenshot after the ClearType change]

Comment: Font rendering was a huge issue in WPF all along. With VS2010 (which is using WPF and new .Net f/w) it's really a great improvement.

Comment: I must admit that I'm normally the picky guy when it comes to fonts (I've opened this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=380919), I really don't see the difference in screenshots above; not even in "m". It looks like the right text is _very_s lightly more "bold", but otherwise the shapes are the same.

Comment: Oh yes, also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651217/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-cleartype

Comment: @Pavel: I did a comparison in an image editor and blew up the text. The text on the right uses more saturated colors, but as you say the shapes are identical. The team may be aiming for equivalence between the rendering engines, but they aren't quite there yet. Different people will have different sensitivities too.

Comment: I don't think they're aiming for pixel-for-pixel equivalence, rather it's about perceived quality being the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like differences in your ClearType settings. Are both screen shots from the same PC?

**Edit:** If Visual Studio 2010 does indeed use WPF internally, the ClearType engine is different and might produce subtly different results. It does however respond to the system-wide ClearType tuner settings. Here's an article that goes into detail:

http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/wpftextclarity.aspx

Comment: This article is outdated now, because font rendering had a major update in WPF 4 (which VS2010 does indeed use). See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=380919

Comment: Both screenshots are from the same PC. In fact, the window of VS2008 is ontop and offset to VS2010. At first I was imagining it (dirty screen, dirty glasses, inside lighting, outside sun), but when I started VS2008 and opened a project I saw the difference immediately. The text was just sharper.